# Pulling data from netty (instead of push for better back pressure control)?

Tags: netty

Does anyone know if the api of netty http server lets the application tell netty when to read more data from sockets?

In the example i see that the consumers registers a handler but i would like to control when the consumer is called and just tell netty to stop fetching data from the socket until i am done processing the current chunks.

I would like to have an asynchronous consumer with back pressure.

Otherwise put, 
 - how do i tell netty (do not feed me more data or feed more data)
 - how do i handle data from netty asynchronously and pause netty during this period (for this request)

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use setAutoRead(false)

see http://normanmaurer.me/presentations/2014-facebook-eng-netty/slides.html#33.0

I couldn't find a better example, but expect someone will present a more complete example.  I think the [FlowControlHandler](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/2b6525856868ab1788db957ff8af8eb22b42c774/handler/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/flow/FlowControlHandler.java) can also help if the data is already read from the the socket, but you just want one message at a time.